# Unable to tweak 2nd GPU fan speed on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: drivers, 20.04, nvidia, graphics, fan

I have 2 graphics card on my PC. One is GTX Titan Xp and the other is ASUS TUF RTX 4090. I wanted to adjust fan speed of 4090 but I got some errors. The OS is Ubuntu 22.04. Here's the detail.

This is what I got by running `nvidia-smi`:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 535.86.10              Driver Version: 535.86.10    CUDA Version: 12.2     |
|-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                 Persistence-M | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                      |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA TITAN Xp                On  | 00000000:21:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 23%   33C    P5              21W / 250W |    337MiB / 12288MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                      |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4090        On  | 00000000:49:00.0 Off |                  Off |
|ERR!   54C    P0              45W / 450W |     16MiB / 24564MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                      |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                                         
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                            |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                            GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                             Usage      |
|=======================================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      2590      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                           95MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2853      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                         91MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      4694      G   ...irefox/3026/usr/lib/firefox/firefox      147MiB |
|    1   N/A  N/A      2590      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                            6MiB |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

We can see the system can read Titan Xp fan speed but reports error for 4090.
This is output of command `sudo nvidia-xconfig --cool-bits=4`:

```
Using X configuration file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf".
Backed up file '/etc/X11/xorg.conf' as '/etc/X11/xorg.conf.backup'
New X configuration file written to '/etc/X11/xorg.conf'
```

After rebooting, if I run command `sudo nvidia-settings -a "[gpu:1]/GPUFanControlState=1" -a "[fan:1]/GPUTargetFanSpeed=55"`, it reports errors:

```
ERROR: An internal driver error occurred

  Attribute 'GPUFanControlState' (RyzenTR:0[gpu:1]) assigned value 1.


ERROR: An internal driver error occurred


ERROR: An internal driver error occurred


ERROR: An internal driver error occurred


ERROR: Error assigning value 55 to attribute 'GPUTargetFanSpeed' (RyzenTR:0[fan:1]) as specified in assignment '[fan:1]/GPUTargetFanSpeed=55' (Unknown
       Error).
```

I tried reinstalling the nvidia driver in terminal but it does not solve the issue. Is there a way to solve this?